# MySQL Function Add prices from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sum

The DB has a few tables, tblPizza and then tables for its toppings, tblCheese, tblMeat, and tblVeggie.  I want to write a MySQL function that'll take VARCHAR params, look up the priceFactor in each table, add them together, and return that decimal.  After Googling and searching here, I've cobbled together this.  None of the results I've found here or on the Googles are trying to do close enough to what I want to do to be an answer.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `dbname`.`calculatePrice` (cheese VARCHAR(50), meat VARCHAR(50), veg VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS DECIMAL
BEGIN
DECLARE price DECIMAL;
SET price = SUM(SELECT priceFactor AS cheesePrice UNION ALL SELECT priceFactor AS meatPrice FROM tblMeat WHERE meatName = meat UNION ALL SELECT priceFactor AS vegPrice FROM tblVeggie WHERE veggieName = veg) FROM tblCheese WHERE cheeseName = cheese);

RETURN price;
END
```

MySQL doesn't like the SELECT after SUM, but I don't know how to get what I want without subqueries.  There's duplicate column names accross each table and no correlation between the tables to justify a JOIN.

The result will be kicked back to PHP, which will JSON it along to jQuery.

Thanks!  99% of the time, I can find exactly what I need here ^_^

Edited to note that it's possible one (but only one) of the params may be null.  The user is only required to select two pizza toppings, but cannot select any less than that.

Comment: Have you tried select sum( priceFactor ) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SET price = 
(
    SELECT  SUM(x.Price) 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT priceFactor AS Price FROM tblCheese WHERE cheeseName = cheese
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT priceFactor AS Price FROM tblMeat WHERE meatName = meat 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT priceFactor AS Price FROM tblVeggie WHERE veggieName = veg
    ) x
);
```